# zippyshare.com direct download links

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a script which gives me direct links to files on zippyshare.com. There is a JS function responsible for the href of the download button. It calculates a value which is necessary for the direct link. For example, the file under this link http://www25.zippyshare.com/v/50781357/file.html brings this:

```
<a id="dlbutton" href="#"><img src="/images/download.png" alt="Download" border="0"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var somffunction = function() {
       var a = 469398;
       document.getElementById('dlbutton').omg = 469401%78956;
       var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('dlbutton').omg) * (469401%3);
       var e = function() {if (false) {return a+b+c} else {return (a+3)%b + 3}};
       document.getElementById('dlbutton').href    = "http://www25.zippyshare.com/d/50781357/"+(b+18)+"/Groove%20Coverage%20-%20Holy%20Virgin%20%28Rob%20Mayth%20Remix%29%204clubbers.com.pl.mp3";
   };
</script>
```

The main problem is, the value of **var a** is different everytime. I tried to access this value with PHP and then I built some script to calculate the value which is the part of the direct link:

```
function zippy_id($zippylink)
 {
    $content = file_get_contents($zippylink);
    $val = explode('var a = ',$content);
    $val = explode(';',$val[1]);
    $val = $val[0];
    return (($val+3) % 78956 * (($val+3) % 3)) + 18;
}
```

The function doesn't give the right value. Can anyone validate this PHP function? Does anybody see a better solution to get direct download links?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can ignore your ever changing `a`, but instead read the other value and adjust your formula, the function `e()` is just a distraction:

```
return (469401 % 78956) * (469401 % 3) + 18;
```

---

Though this highly looks like inappropriate usage.

Comment: That might be, but in the function a never is used to calculate the result of b, thus b + 18

Comment: Anyway, I thought there can be problem with session. The number is calculated the same way by my PHP function but the link probably works on the server which called it and has currently a certain `var a` value.

Comment: The number is the same, that's correct, but it highly depends on the request you're doing then... If you open the url in a new browser with no session than that might be a problem, since the page probably is using some kind of hotlinking prevention. My thought was that the valid number is stored in a session variable and then be checked on the next call, but old links still work, so this doesn't seem to be the case.